# Why do the same results returned by two different calls in my c code?

Tags: c

I've compiled it on the Debian platform with GCC(4.9.2).

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static const char *msg[] = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Thuesday"};
static char buf[20];

char *getday(int idx) {
    strcpy(buf, msg[idx]);
    return buf;
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%s %s\n", getday(0), getday(1));
    return 0;
}
```

It looks work well but always printf the same string(**Sunday**).But why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getday` returns the address of `buf`. Thus `printf` gets the same parameter twice (the address of `buf`). `buf` contains the string *"Sunday"* when `printf` evaluates its parameters, because first `getday(1)` is executed (in your case the compiler choses the right-most parameter first), filling `buf` with the string *"Monday"*, then `getday(0)` is executed, filling `buf` with the string *"Sunday"*, and then `printf` uses the data at the given address (which is "Sunday").

To fix this you must either copy the return value of `getday()` into separate local buffers and pass those to `printf`, or you must return different addresses each time, e.g. by returning the address in the array `msg`, instead of `buf`, e.g. so:

```
char *getday(int idx) {
    return msg[idx];
}
```

Comment: C does not define the order of evaluation of function parameters. The program could legally print either `Sunday Sunday` or `Monday Monday`.

Comment: Indeed, since the `msg` array already exists, there's almost certainly no good reason to copy its contents to another array. `return msg[idx];` is better in multiple ways.

Answer (score 1):

functions in parameters to `printf` are called before the `printf` itself. Since both calls return address to the same buffer, the last call creates its contents. (there is no defined order in which functions in parameters are called).

As a result you call printf with 3 args, where the last 2 have the same pointer to the same buffer with the same content.

Comment: To expand on this a bit, the function `getday` does not return "Sunday" on one call and "Monday" on another. Both calls return the same value, the address of `buf`. By the time `printf` is called, `buf` contains one of those strings (which one it contains is unspecified).